# MPMediaQuery returning tracks instead of playlist from persistentID

Tags: ios, objective-c, media-player, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

The purpose of my code is to return an MPMediaPlaylist object, from a persistentID previously attained.

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:persistentID
                                                                       forProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPersistentID];
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
[query addFilterPredicate:predicate];
```

The `query.items` are the tracks included in the playlist. What I want to be returned is the playlist itself. How do I get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlaylist_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMediaPlaylist

for code that shows you how to get a playlist:

```
MPMediaQuery *myPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
NSArray *playlists = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];

for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in playlists) {
    NSLog (@"%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);
    // ...
}
```

What you are actually getting is a list of songs (the `items`), but they are *grouped* by playlist. That is why asking for the query's `collections` gets you references to the `MPMediaPlaylist` objects you are after.

Comment: For me most important point is to get query object by [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery] and then add predicate. Thanks!